# Unable to compile MacVim with filedrawer on OSX 10.7.5

Tags: macvim

I am unable to compile [Alloy's fork of MacVim](https://github.com/alloy/macvim) on OS X 10.7.5. I have Xcode 4.6 installed, with up-to-date command line tools.  (I am aware that there is a Homebrew formula for this version of Macvim, but I am a MacPorts user, and I would rather not switch to Homebrew just to resolve this.) I also tried running "CC=clang LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib ./configure ...." but still hit errors. Any help is appreciated!

I have heard that MacVim has issues compiling with Ruby 1.9, so I used my system ruby (after trying multiple times with 1.9.3 and 1.9.2):

```
$ rvm system
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]
$ ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-rubyinterp


$ cd src && make first
xcodebuild -project MacVim/MacVim.xcodeproj 
=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET PSMTabBarControlFramework OF PROJECT PSMTabBarControl WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===
Check dependencies

CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMOverflowPopUpButton.o source/PSMOverflowPopUpButton.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/PSMTabBarControl.hmap -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release -include /var/folders/2x/_8nyw24s4bv5ccy2z6gf9hd80000gp/C/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/AppKit-dznbmxptlydmqxbpwpoxawqdnnsw/AppKit.h -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMOverflowPopUpButton.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMOverflowPopUpButton.dia -c /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/source/PSMOverflowPopUpButton.m -o /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMOverflowPopUpButton.o
fatal error: file '/usr/include/sys/types.h' has been modified since the precompiled header was built
1 error generated.

CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMMetalTabStyle.o source/PSMMetalTabStyle.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/PSMTabBarControl.hmap -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release -include /var/folders/2x/_8nyw24s4bv5ccy2z6gf9hd80000gp/C/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/AppKit-dznbmxptlydmqxbpwpoxawqdnnsw/AppKit.h -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMMetalTabStyle.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMMetalTabStyle.dia -c /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/source/PSMMetalTabStyle.m -o /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMMetalTabStyle.o
fatal error: file '/usr/include/sys/types.h' has been modified since the precompiled header was built
1 error generated.

CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMRolloverButton.o source/PSMRolloverButton.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/PSMTabBarControl.hmap -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release -include /var/folders/2x/_8nyw24s4bv5ccy2z6gf9hd80000gp/C/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/AppKit-dznbmxptlydmqxbpwpoxawqdnnsw/AppKit.h -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMRolloverButton.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMRolloverButton.dia -c /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/source/PSMRolloverButton.m -o /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMRolloverButton.o
fatal error: file '/usr/include/sys/types.h' has been modified since the precompiled header was built
1 error generated.

CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMTabBarCell.o source/PSMTabBarCell.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/PSMTabBarControl.hmap -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release -include /var/folders/2x/_8nyw24s4bv5ccy2z6gf9hd80000gp/C/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/AppKit-dznbmxptlydmqxbpwpoxawqdnnsw/AppKit.h -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMTabBarCell.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMTabBarCell.dia -c /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/source/PSMTabBarCell.m -o /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMTabBarCell.o
fatal error: file '/usr/include/sys/types.h' has been modified since the precompiled header was built
1 error generated.

CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMProgressIndicator.o source/PSMProgressIndicator.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/PSMTabBarControl.hmap -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release -include /var/folders/2x/_8nyw24s4bv5ccy2z6gf9hd80000gp/C/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/AppKit-dznbmxptlydmqxbpwpoxawqdnnsw/AppKit.h -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMProgressIndicator.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMProgressIndicator.dia -c /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/source/PSMProgressIndicator.m -o /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMProgressIndicator.o
fatal error: file '/usr/include/sys/types.h' has been modified since the precompiled header was built
1 error generated.

CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMAquaTabStyle.o source/PSMAquaTabStyle.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/PSMTabBarControl.hmap -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release -include /var/folders/2x/_8nyw24s4bv5ccy2z6gf9hd80000gp/C/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/AppKit-dznbmxptlydmqxbpwpoxawqdnnsw/AppKit.h -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMAquaTabStyle.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMAquaTabStyle.dia -c /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/source/PSMAquaTabStyle.m -o /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMAquaTabStyle.o
fatal error: file '/usr/include/sys/types.h' has been modified since the precompiled header was built
1 error generated.

CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMTabDragAssistant.o source/PSMTabDragAssistant.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/PSMTabBarControl.hmap -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release -include /var/folders/2x/_8nyw24s4bv5ccy2z6gf9hd80000gp/C/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/AppKit-dznbmxptlydmqxbpwpoxawqdnnsw/AppKit.h -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMTabDragAssistant.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMTabDragAssistant.dia -c /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/source/PSMTabDragAssistant.m -o /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMTabDragAssistant.o
fatal error: file '/usr/include/sys/types.h' has been modified since the precompiled header was built
1 error generated.

CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMUnifiedTabStyle.o source/PSMUnifiedTabStyle.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/PSMTabBarControl.hmap -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/Release -include /var/folders/2x/_8nyw24s4bv5ccy2z6gf9hd80000gp/C/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/AppKit-dznbmxptlydmqxbpwpoxawqdnnsw/AppKit.h -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMUnifiedTabStyle.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMUnifiedTabStyle.dia -c /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/source/PSMUnifiedTabStyle.m -o /Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMUnifiedTabStyle.o
fatal error: file '/usr/include/sys/types.h' has been modified since the precompiled header was built
1 error generated.

2013-02-20 17:00:21.728 xcodebuild[72127:4f03]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-2108/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:87
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMTabDragAssistant.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “PSMTabDragAssistant.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x40175cf20 {NSFilePath=/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMTabDragAssistant.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x40175caa0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMTabDragAssistant.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *, void (^)(NSString *))
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40175bc20>{name = (null), num = 4}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2013-02-20 17:00:21.734 xcodebuild[72127:4f03]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-2108/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:87
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMUnifiedTabStyle.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “PSMUnifiedTabStyle.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x400127680 {NSFilePath=/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMUnifiedTabStyle.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x40172c800 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/Users/mxxx/src/macvim/src/MacVim/PSMTabBarControl/../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMUnifiedTabStyle.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *, void (^)(NSString *))
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40175bc20>{name = (null), num = 4}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMOverflowPopUpButton.o source/PSMOverflowPopUpButton.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMMetalTabStyle.o source/PSMMetalTabStyle.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMRolloverButton.o source/PSMRolloverButton.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMTabBarCell.o source/PSMTabBarCell.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMProgressIndicator.o source/PSMProgressIndicator.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMAquaTabStyle.o source/PSMAquaTabStyle.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMTabDragAssistant.o source/PSMTabDragAssistant.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC ../build/PSMTabBarControl.build/Release/PSMTabBarControlFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PSMUnifiedTabStyle.o source/PSMUnifiedTabStyle.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(8 failures)
make: *** [macvim] Error 65
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized that there is a set of pre-compiled versions in Alloy's Github repo:

https://github.com/alloy/macvim/downloads

I downloaded build 021120112044 and now everything is working.